# Не работает конф. файл .htaccess в phpstorm

Tags: php, .htaccess, phpstorm

Желаю сделать единую точку входа для дальнейшей разработки, а PhpStorm (версия 2016.1) не желает обрабатывать .htaccess файл и перенаправлять все запросы в index.php

Код:

```
php_flag display_errors on
php_flag display_startup_errors on
php_value error_reporting 2047
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

RewriteBase /
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*?)(/)?$ index.php?url=$1 [L]
```

В index.php обычный `print_r($_GET)`

Comment: Как это у вас phpstorm обрабатывает .htaccess и перенаправляет на index.php?

Answer (score 2):

Самый простой вариант,скачиваете notepad++,и вперед :)
Вот уже 8 ой год как программированием занимаюсь,
и файлы на подобие htaccess,host,vhosts,и даже sql открываю в нeм.
PHPShtorm,notepad++ itp всего лишь для управление кодом,a в данном случае этот код исполняется на apache servere.Htaccess предназначен для конфигурации apache серверов в Runtime режиме.

Comment: 1) ide всегда удобнее
2) в шторме не нужно заботиться о подъёме сервера на локале
3) проблема не в открытии, а в отсутствие редиректа.

Comment: Виктор htaccess обрабатывается сервером а не PHPstorm , очевидно у вас htaccess с расширением или с именем ,

Comment: @ВикторЕвлампьев Я вам в коментарии задавал вопрос, объясните как у вас обрабатывает phpstorm htaccess?